# Check if Auto Increment exist in a table in derby database

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I have created a table in `Derby Database` with Auto Increment.

```
   For example: 
   CREATE TABLE USERS (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) , USER_NAME)
```

I have to check if the id column detail now,

```
String query = "SELECT ID FROM USERS ";
conn = new Kanexon().db();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

if(rs.next()){
    System.out.println("ColumnLabel: "+rsmd.getColumnLabel(1));
    System.out.println("ColumnName: "+rsmd.getColumnName(1));
    System.out.println("ColumnTypeName: "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
}
```

It gives me output something like this:

```
ColumnLabel: ID
ColumnName: ID
ColumnTypeName: BIGINT
```

Is there a way by which I can check that the `ID` column is auto incremented or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if the column is auto incremented, use the isAutoIncrement method on ResultSetMetadata: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#isAutoIncrement(int)